# how to convert a json format to a jsonb?

Tags: python, postgresql

I am currently working with information in json format and I want to convert it to jsonb in order to update said information in a postgresql database, but I cannot find relevant information that tells me how to do it from python, I appreciate any comments.

Comment: JSONB isn't a format. It's just a PostGres data type for storing JSON.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the_table.the_column of type json, you just execute this:

```
ALTER TABLE the_table ALTER the_column TYPE JSONB;
```

You can do that from python, perl, psql, whatever.  Anything that can send SQL commands.